# Microsoft Access: Replacing Multiple Records in a Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to Microsoft Access.
I have a table ListOfParticipants having columns ID, Name, University, Institution, ...
In the column Institution there is a text, for example: Family member of PersonsName (WIFE).
The task is to replace "(WIFE)" with "Spouse".

However, table has over 1000 names and there is another table containing more than 100 words to be replaced and their new values., for example:

Replacements_Table

| OldValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- |
| Wife | Spouse |
| Son | Child |

I would like to avoid using nested replace statements. How to replace the OldValue from Institution column to a NewValue using the Replacements_Table?

I tried Example 2 from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2093/standardize-text-with-multi-search-and-replace-function-in-sql-server/ but I got an error "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE','INSERT','PROCEDURE','SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: The example you refer to is an antipattern Microsoft warns us against here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 (see part C). You can achieve this by writing a VBA function which opens a recordset to the replacements table and performs replacements on its argument repeatedly (one for each row in replacements), and returning the result. You can use this to update, if you wish. Wouldn;t be very fast for large sets.